# Merge sort mergin

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I am trying to implement merge sort.

I have declared merge function

```
void mergeSort( vector<int> &a  , int low , int high){
    if( low < high){
        int mid = (low + high ) / 2;
        mergeSort( a  , low , mid);
        mergeSort( a , mid + 1 , high);
        mergeArays( a , low , mid , high);
    }
}
```

however i have trouble with merge , i have declared

```
void mergeArays( vector<int> &a , int low , int mid , int high){
    int i = 0;
    int j = mid + 1;
    vector<int> final;
    while( i != mid && j!= high){
        if( a[i] < a[j]){
            final.push_back(a[i++]);
            continue;
        }
        final.push_back(a[j++]);
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < final.size() ;i++){
        a[i] = final[i];
    }
}
```

with input `9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1` , it throws competely wrong output. Where is a bug or mistake in my logic behind merge? I fail to find it , everytime i try to calcualte it it should be good.

Thanks

Comment: Off the top, `int i = 0;` probably should be `int i = low;`. Aren't you surprised that you pass `low` in but never use it?

Comment: didnt notice it , thanks ,but it still throws wrong output >{

Comment: `final` has `high - low` elements representing the sorted `[low, high]` range. But you copy it into `a` starting from 0, not `low`.

Comment: Also, if elements in the `[mid, high]` range are used up first in the merge loop, you never copy the remaining elements in the `[low, mid]` range.

Comment: More generally, now would be a good time to learn to use your debugger.

Comment: Show us your call to the functions.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is to use your debugger, but not to ask at Stack Overflow before you did so. Tell us all your observations you made when inspecting your code stepping through line by line in 1st place. Also you might want to read [**How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**]  At least leave us with a **[MCVE]** that reproduces your problem. (This is a personal stock comment provided by πάντα ῥεῖ™)

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug here in your `mergeArrays` method. Consider the loop:

```
while( i != mid && j!= high){
    if( a[i] < a[j]){
        final.push_back(a[i++]);
        continue;
    }
    final.push_back(a[j++]);
}
```

Now, imagine that you're merging 2-element subarrays. Those are:

```
[3,9]    // a[i] = 3, a[i+1] = 9
[10,12]  // j[i] = 10, j[i+1] = 12
```

So according to your code, it's going to output 3 and 9, and then the loop will exit, because `i == mid`.

You need to clean up after the loop to make sure everything gets copied. Correct code would be:

```
while( i != mid && j!= high){
    if( a[i] < a[j]){
        final.push_back(a[i++]);
        continue;
    }
    final.push_back(a[j++]);
}
while (i != mid)
{
    final.push_back(a[i++]);
}
while (j != high)
{
    final.push_back(a[j++]);
}
```

Note that only one of those two cleanup loops will be entered, because for the first loop to exit, either `i == mid` or `j == high`.